# how not to show the report in sql if the task is completed?

Tags: sql, oracle

Table 1:

```
id    name    desc     start date     end date
----------------------------------------------
1     a       abc        1/2/2010    
2     b       def        2/4/2012     2/2/2016
3     c       adf        3/1/2015     
4     d       dde        2/2/2011     3/3/2012
```

if the end date is given or submited by user I jus want to see the output as

```
   id    name    desc     start date     end date
    ----------------------------------------------

    1     a       abc        1/2/2010 

    3     c       adf        3/1/2015
```

Comment: Hint:  `where end_date is null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Select * from table where end_date is null`

would give you the answer in your example

Comment: use 4 spaces at the front of each line of code/data/error msgs OR highlight a block of text and use the `{}` format tool at the top left of the edit box to format as `code/data/output/errorMsgs`. For more info see  [editing-help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

The below query would give the results of the table where end date is null

```
Select * from tablename
where enddate is null;
```

Comment: if Suppose is my start date is connected to end date ..suppose we using a case statement like                                                                         
                CASE
               WHEN startdate= 'somevalue' THEN 1
               ELSE NULL
            END

Comment: select 
case when startdate = sysdate then 1
else null
end
 from tablename;

Or you could also add a date to the start date

select case when startdate = to_date('01/02/2010','mm/dd/yyyy') then 1 else null end from tablename

Comment: what does your answer distinguish from the answer that SCJohnson243 posted  40 minutes  before your answer?

Comment: I did not see the answer which was provided. You can disregard this if you do not want to